# ElasticSearch combine match and function score queries

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a complicated query to run in elasticsearch that spans across multiple fields (nested and non-nested). I am using a `bool should` query across a `multi-field match` and `nested field match`.

Additionally I want a composite scoring which takes into account several other parameters such as location, rating etc.

I tried to run a simplified proof of concept combined query which looks for a matching term and tries to use function score for the other fields but I am running into an error from es.

```
GET init/restaurant/_search/
{


         "query": { 
           "match": {
           "cuisine_categories": "Oriental"
           },
          "function_score": {
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "gauss": {
                      "coordinates": { 
                        "origin": { "lat": 74.20, "lon": 31.23 },
                        "offset": "1km",
                        "scale":  "3km"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "gauss": {
                      "nomnom_rating": { 
                        "origin": "4.5", 
                        "offset": "0.5",
                        "scale":  "1"
                      }
                    },
                    "weight": 2
                  },
                  {
                    "gauss": {
                      "estimated_preparation_time": {
                        "origin": "30",
                        "offset": "10",
                        "scale": "20"
                      }
                    },
                      "weight": 5
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is not a valid. The `match` clause should be within the query object of `function score` as shown below

Example:

```
POST init/restaurant/_search/
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "gauss": {
                  "coordinates": {
                     "origin": {
                        "lat": 74.2,
                        "lon": 31.23
                     },
                     "offset": "1km",
                     "scale": "3km"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "gauss": {
                  "nomnom_rating": {
                     "origin": "4.5",
                     "offset": "0.5",
                     "scale": "1"
                  }
               },
               "weight": 2
            },
            {
               "gauss": {
                  "estimated_preparation_time": {
                     "origin": "30",
                     "offset": "10",
                     "scale": "20"
                  }
               },
               "weight": 5
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "cuisine_categories": "Oriental"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I got a "Expected field name but got a start object' exception with your query.

Comment: Life Saver!  Works with everything,